# Firebase reading data from multiple references

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase database from multiple child in single function. I have two child nodes in Firebase `Favorites` and `Users`

I am using RecyclerView to show list of Favorites User but i want to fetch one value name "Online" from Users node.

I add `addValueEventListener` on Favorites and add `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on Users within Favorites addValueEventListener, but my addListenerForSingleValueEvent give null value. 
There is my code:

```
        mFavouriteDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mList.clear();
                if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0){
                    for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        final Favourites user = snap.getValue(Favourites.class);
                        final FavouritesList[] holdObj = null;
                        //if not current user, as we do not want to show ourselves then chat with ourselves lol
                        try {
                            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(user.getUserId())){
                                //Firebase Reading data
                                mUsersDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                                mUsersDBRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        mUsersDBRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("online").onDisconnect().setValue(false);
                                        String local =dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("online").getValue().toString();
                                        if(local.equals("true")){

                                            holdObj[0] = new FavouritesList(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),user.getFavouriteId(),user.getFavouriteName(),user.getFavouriteCity(),user.getFavouriteCountry(),user.getFavouriteAge(),user.getFavouriteGender(),user.getFavouriteKeyword(),user.getPushKey(), "true","Link");
                                        }else{

                                            holdObj[0] = new FavouritesList(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),user.getFavouriteId(),user.getFavouriteName(),user.getFavouriteCity(),user.getFavouriteCountry(),user.getFavouriteAge(),user.getFavouriteGender(),user.getFavouriteKeyword(),user.getPushKey(), "false","Link");
                                        }

                                        mList.add(holdObj[0]);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                populaterecyclerView();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here my populaterecyclerView(); Class

```
 private void populaterecyclerView(){
    adapter = new UserFavouritesMeHomeListAdapter(context,mList);
    adapter.setClickListener(UserFavouritesMeListHomeFragment.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thanks

Link of Image: 
http://userdata.in/singls/images/profile/WobiUh7Zb2bjszmYN0LofK7Pm0z1_20180124042847_file_cover.jpg

Data want to fetch from while reading Favorite 
http://userdata.in/singls/images/profile/WobiUh7Zb2bjszmYN0LofK7Pm0z1_20180124044659_file_cover.jpg

Comment: Show us your database structure and indicate the exact results you want to achieve.

Comment: My main child contain 2 childs

Comment: 1-Favorite 2-Users,i want to read all child values from Favorite and one value online from user and set them into recyclerview

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, show us your database structure (add a part of your JSON file or a screenshot) and indicate the exact results you want to achieve.

Comment: @AlexMamo i attach the image link of my database..

Comment: i want to read the Favorites and Favorite also contain User Id from that particular user ID i want to read User,and want to read the User also

Comment: @AlexMamo I attach 2 images at the end of question

Comment: I'm sorry but none of your images works.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @AlexMamo please see my problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259345/combining-two-arrays-of-model-class-type-firebase-android